# Convert a plane from Point/Normal/D to plane equation

Tags: math, plane

I have a plane class that stores a plane as

```
Vector position;
Vector normal;
float d;
```

(Vector is just x,y,z in a helper class)

Been using it for years, serves almost all my purposes.  However, I use it as a savant without really thinking much about how/why it works.

So... I need to convert it to to a float[4] format for a friend to use for some OpenGL rendering.  What's the right way to convert point/normal/d to the plane equation in float[4]?  Everything I try seems to be off a little bit.

[Edit]
This is the plane's Create() function, which assigns a value to d...

```
void            Create(Vector thePoint, Vector theNormal)
    {
        theNormal.Normalize();
        pos=thePoint;
        normal=theNormal;
        d=-theNormal.Dot(thePoint);
    }
```

Comment: What is `d` in this plane class? A plane can be uniquely defined in 3D space with a position and a normal. The plane equation (Ax + By + Cz + D = 0) specifies a plane with a normal (A, B, C) and a single value that defines the distance from the origin to the plane (in the direction of the normal). But if you have a point on the plane, you don't *need* D. So what is this `d` in your structure?

Comment: I've edited the main text to show how d is computed.  It's the negative dot product of the normal and the position.  HOWEVER, I have tried building my four floats out of pos.x*normal.x+pos.y*normal.y+pos.z*normal.z+d, producing only comic results.

Comment: The position is superfluous for the definition of an infinite plane. All you need is the normal vector and the distance from the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using homogeneous coordinates points are

```
 Point = [x,y,z,1]
```

To define the equation of a plane

[image: eq1]

you need the following 4 values for the coordinates of the plane

```
Plane = [n_x,n_y,n_z,-d]
```

Where `(n_x,n_y,n_z)` is the normal vector, and `d` the distance to the origin.

Now taking the dot product of the point and the plane yields the equation

```
[x,y,z,1] . [n_x,n_y,n_z,-d] = 0

x*n_x + y*n_y + z*n_z - d = 0
```

In `C#` code this is

```
public float[] GetCoord(Plane plane)
{
   return new float[] { plane.normal.X, plane.normal.Y, plane.normal.Z, -plane.d };
}
```

Comment: Negating D was about the only combination I didn't try.  Thankya stranger.